# Which inputs produced the ith output of outer in R?

Tags: r, indexing

R has the function `outer` that allows you to compute a function for every combination of inputs `xs` and `ys`, e.g.:

```
xs <- 1:5
ys <- 0:10
zs <- outer(xs, ys, Vectorize(function(x, y) sin(x) + y**2))
```

Let's say I want to know the minimal value in `zs`:

```
> min(zs)
[1] -0.9589243
```

and what position it's in:

```
> which(zs==min(zs))
[1] 5
```

Now how can I figure out which x of `xs` and which y of `ys` produced the 5th z of `zs`?

I can recompute using something like `outer(xs, ys, Vectorize(function(x, y) paste(x,y)))[which(zs==min(zs))]` to get a string of the indices, but this seems bloody inefficient to me. What's a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use:

```
which(zs==min(zs), arr.ind=T)
#     row col
#[1,]   5   1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use arr.index=TRUE

```
which(zs==min(zs),arr.ind = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

One can use `expand.grid`:

```
> expand.grid(xs, ys)[zs==min(zs),]
  Var1 Var2
5    5    0
```